# Minimum and Maximum of an order

Tags: order-theory

I've got an order in my assignment

```
R={⟨a,b⟩,⟨a,c⟩,⟨a,d⟩,⟨b,c⟩,⟨a,a⟩,⟨b,b⟩,⟨c,c⟩,⟨d,d⟩}
```

with the quantity of

```
A={a,b,c,d}
```

and have to give the maximal elements, the minimal elements, minimum and maximum. I' very confused since I find a lot about minimum and maximum in orders of numbers but not in an example like this. It's not clear to me what the actual difference between minimal element and minimum is.

Comment: Why don't you try drawing a diagram?

Comment: Draw a Hasse diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)

Comment: I think this helped! Thank you both.